# Is there an option to edit title-parameter for Links in Redactor?

Tags: redactor, richtext, titles

How can i edit Link-Title in Redactor Richtext-Editor? Didn't found any config options or plugins for that. Can't believe this is not possible yet.

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no out-of-the-box way with Redactor, other than to open the HTML source view and adjust the `<a>` tag manually to be something like `<a href="yourlink" title="yourtitle">`.

All Redactor settings regarding links can be found here: http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/links/